# Error Upgrading Magento 1.3 to 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, upgrade

One of my clients asked me to upgrade his website which was built on Magento 1.3, now I am trying to upgrade it to Magento 1.4 so that I can upgrade it to Magento 1.7.

Magento Connect is not working here. So I am using SSH but when I try to initialize pear through this command:

```
./pear mage-setup
```

it throws the error:

```
Could not open the file /path/pearmage.php
```

Without initializing pear i can not proceed.

Please help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just copy the new magento version over?

Comment: Looks like a missing '/' in the include path. Did you find an answer? Please share the mistake with us and mark it as solution!

Comment: Consider getting the 1.5 installer in place if you're going to upgrade that way, the old 1.3 installer's pear may have major issues with running under the newer versions of PHP. It was just plain easier to extract all the files in the 1.4.2.0 download package and copy it directly over the top of the previous version using SCP while taking care to keep your customized .htaccess file. I've always found Connect to be an incomplete answer that always needs to be run at least twice to do the same upgrade which gets done accurately in a single pass with a direct file copy. As Fabian says...

Comment: I don't know that the 1.3 PEAR installer is maintained. .. rather copy the core over and cross your fingers...

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you will need to move your theme as well it would be better to point a new version of Magento 1.7 at your old database and run the upgrade.

After that you will want to move each module over and test, many won't work

Finally you will have to think about how you want to do your theme. There was no BASE folder in 1.3 so you will want to make your new theme off the current base version.

Typically we will diff the files from the old theme to see how much we can re-use, but more likely you will want to use re-do your theme using all the new layout and design files from Magento 1.7

Comment: Definitely get your templates and layouts working first. And then work on any custom modules you've created. Finally, all third party modules need to be upgraded to versions that will survive the transition. The jump from 1.3 to 1.4.1.1 was drastic and a lot of the custom template uneeded because of the fallback introduced (base folder). The jump from 1.4.1.1 to 1.4.2.0 was nearly as messy but with a lot less template work. The major issue was getting the database to upgrade. Going to 1.5.1.0 was a breeze with some module rework. It does get a bit easier as you get to newer versions.